# Obtain value of Primary Key for Trigger Updated Row (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I wish to identify the value for the `PRIMARY KEY` of the row that I have just updated.
i.e : `X` is an `int` value `PRIMARY KEY` on the `person` table.

This trigger works when I manually enter the `int` value e.g replace `X` with 1001.

```
use mydatabase;
DROP TRIGGER update_approved;
delimiter $
CREATE TRIGGER update_approved AFTER UPDATE ON person
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE referral_person SET
    approved = 1 WHERE
    id = X;
END$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change it to

```
....
id = OLD.ColumnName
```

where `ColumnName` is the name of your *primary key column*.